# Which version of OpenMP implements gcc 4.5?

Tags: software-center, gcc

I am using Ubuntu 11.04. I have installed the compiler gcc 4.5 by using the command sudo apt-get install gcc 4.5 in terminal. Now I need the command to enable OpenMP. Is it gcc -fopenmp foo.c ?

---

@pl1nk
 I started from the beginning:

1st step=> **sudo apt-get install build-essential**

2nd step=> **sudo apt-get install gcc 4.5**

And now the output of gcc -v is:

```
**ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.5 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --with-multiarch-defaults=i386-linux-gnu --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.5 --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-gold --enable-ld=default --with-plugin-ld=ld.gold --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4)** 

In few words the same results....
What should I do now?
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `update-alternatives --config gcc` 
to be asked to choose the GCC version you want to use among those installed.

Then you could run gcc with the chosen version.

Comment: It looks like there is only one version

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ update-alternatives --config gcc
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gcc.

Comment: @Anita7 How did you install gcc 4.5?

What´s the output of `ggc -v`

Comment: I have installed the compiler gcc 4.5 by using the command sudo apt-get install gcc 4.5

Comment: @Anita7 It seems that you have only gcc 4.5 installed. You can proceed with `gcc -fopenmp foo.c` as you mentioned.

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ gcc -fopenmp foo.c
gcc: foo.c: No such file or directory
gcc: no input files

Comment: @Anita7 too many comments! You should add the output and refine your answer.

Comment: But that is the uotput of gcc -v :S

Comment: @ You should avoid extended discussion in comments, please move the comments with the output by placing them to your answer (use edit to do that). Other than that it makes your answer easily readable.

Answer (score 0):

GCC 4.4/5 implements OpenMP version 3.0.

GCC 4.7/8 supports the OpenMP 3.1 specification.

GCC 4.9 supports OpenMP 4.0. Ubuntu 13.10, however, uses GCC 4.8 by default.

For more information, see [OpenMP in the GCC wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/openmp).

According to the gcc man page, `gcc -fopenmp foo.c` is indeed the correct syntax.

The man page also states:

> -fopenmp
>
> Enable handling of OpenMP directives "#pragma omp" in C/C ++ and "!$omp" in Fortran. When -fopenmp is specified, the compiler generates parallel code according to the OpenMP Application Program Interface v3.0 http://www.openmp.org/. This option implies -pthread, and thus is only supported on targets that have support for -pthread.